# How to write conditional order by clause criteria in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, criteria

I need to convert below query in hibernate criteria.

Any one have idea how to write this order by clause in hibernate?

```
select * from StudentMasterTable where SchoolId = 90 and SchoolName IS NOT NULL ORDER BY IIF(StudentType = 'O',StudentName,SchoolName)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i found solution for this.

i created a custom class to override the criteria formula.

```
public class customOrderBy extends Order {
    private String sqlFormula;


    protected OrderBySqlFormula(String sqlFormula) {
        super(sqlFormula, true);
        this.sqlFormula = sqlFormula;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return sqlFormula;
    }

    public String toSqlString(Criteria criteria, CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery) throws HibernateException {
        return sqlFormula;
    }


    public static Order customOrder(String sqlFormula) {
        return new OrderBySqlFormula(sqlFormula);
    }
}
```

And i called this as below

```
criteria.addOrder(customOrderBy.customOrder("IIF(StudentType = 'O',StudentName,SchoolName)"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe i did something like this to deal with dynamic orderBys:

//make a method that will take in a string which is I guess your studentType column(you probably should have shown your entity class for StudentMasterTable, I assumed studentType was type of String).

```
String orderByClause(String s){
String result = "";
if(s.equals('O'))
   result = "s.studentType";

   return result;

}
```

//then do the below

```
"select s from StudentMasterTable s where s.schoolId = '90' and s.schoolName is not    null
order by " +  orderByClause(s.studentType) + ",s.studentName,s.schoolName";
```

Comment: i dont have StudentType in request i need to do order by by checking the data which is in table or in bean looking for criteria based solution